# Links On Reports

Tags: administration, reports-api, joined-reports, custom-reports

Hello I have a report which lists all transactions. Now is it possible to put a custom link on report row which takes the record Id and opens another page by sending the Id ?

Like formula or something `/apex/Trade_Document_SO_PDF?id={TransactionId}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlinks work fine in a report. However you would have to create a formula field on the object to show the contents of this field in your report, since it's not possible in reports to create row level formula's.

Ik looks like that's no big deal as long as you refer to existing documents of which you know the url.